# Convert website images for dark mode

Tags: images, color-conversion, video

I just converted my website to dark mode so it chooses the user system settings. However, most of my images and videos look horrible (too white). Are there any tools to **automatically** convert images and videos so they look great when in dark mode? This is an example:
[image]

Comment: So if you have an image of for example a polar bear you want some automatic tool which will make it black? And a bright sky should somehow become darker? People's clothes turning darker? I don't think this will ever work. How should a script know what *you* consider "great" in dark mode? Could you show some examples of before and after the wanted conversion? You could easily find a way to darken all images, but I don't think it's the result you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not talking about photos, but images and videos that are the result of simulations. Indeed I wouldn't be asking this if I had a blue sky in a photo. Added an example.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Any automated solution would merely toggle values, **all values**. Automation would *never* know what *should* be adjusted and what *shouldn't*. What needs adjustment could only ever be determined by a *human* operator.

---

That being posted, you *could* merely "invert" all images... quick, easy, and simple.. but results will be largely unpredictable and in most instances not as striking as the original image.

[image]
<sub>Straight, unrefined, Invert via Photoshop</sub>

---

Even in browsers/operating systems *each and every image* used in the UI is often *different* and adjusted in a manual fashion to be best suited for dark mode. i.e. the global mode switch isn't "automatically" doing *anything*, other than *referencing* different images.

Comment: You talking about inverting images made me think of [this](https://www.gwern.net/Red) site where you can toggle light/dark mode in the upper right corner. Some images on the site have a class named ".invertible" with this css: `filter: grayscale(50%) invert(100%) brightness(95%) hue-rotate(180deg);`, which desaturates a bit, inverts, darkens and rotates the hue back to normal. Other images which are not suitable for being inverted are just desaturated a bit with `filter: grayscale(50%);`.